# Positioning sun light to get drop shadow or an object in orthographic view

Tags: lighting, shadows

I got a cube with some reflective material applied to it, behind it is a plane which has shadow catcher nodes set up. From an angle I can see the shadow behind the cube, but in orthographic camera view I cant figure out how to position the sunlight to get the drop shadow. I've attached an example how I have positioned the light. I tried various angles and positioning on the Z axis but I cant get it to appear.

thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to note, probably including ones you already know:

- The location of a Sun lamp makes no difference - it's infinitely far away, and its rays are parallel. Put it somewhere convenient, and adjust only its orientation
- The 'angle' setting in the lamp's *Data* tab > *Light* panel will harden or soften the shadow
- If your World has an HDRI, or is making a contribution through its color, the   the sun's shadow will be somewhat filled by the ambient light.
- Shadow Catcher is a Cycles-only feature, and only useful on transparent film.. Corrected! See edit.

EDIT:Thanks to  @blenderbreath, who tells me there's a shadow-catcher for EEVEE, which I've never used ..  Here it is:

[image]

I would suggest giving the plane an ordinary diffuse white material during adjustment, to make sure it can be seen at all, before switching its setting to Shadow Catcher

Comment: Hi Robbin, all points taken which you stated. But there is a shadow catcher for eevee which fakes the shadow using a plane.

Comment: @blenderbreath   Oh... thanks so much! I'm behind the times. Do you want to edit the answer?

Comment: Sure, no problem, here's the node set up as seen in a tutorial on YT for EEVEE shadow catcher: https://ibb.co/9G9XVST

Comment: @blenderbreath .. Thanks! inserted.  I'll delete (now) surplus comments after a while..